# add animation to javascript using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the below code to add animation to the slideshow using css. But the animation is applied only to the first image and not to other images. how do I add the transition to other images as well using css only?

```
<html>
    <style>
        #slideshow{width:310;height:210;border-style:solid;}
        #imge{
            position:absolute;left:15;top:15;
            animation:myfirst 3s;}
        @keyframes myfirst
        {
            from {width:0;}
        to {width:300;}
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
        {
            from {width:0;}
        to {width:300;}
        }

    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="slideshow">
            <img id="imge" src="img1.jpg" height="200" width="300">
        </div>
        <script>
            var count=1;
            mf();
            function mf()
            {
                document.getElementById("imge").src="img"+count+".jpg";

                if(count<3)
                    count++;
                else
                    count=1;
                setTimeout("mf()",3000);
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS3 animation property **animation-iteration-count**

Specifies the number of times an animation is played. Default 1,so make it to infinite

Try this code:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/a7uq9/)**:

```
#slideshow{width:310px;height:210px;border-style:solid;}
#imge{
position:absolute;left:15;top:15;
width:310px;height:210px;
animation:myfirst 3s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation:myfirst 5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;}

@keyframes myfirst
{
from {width:0px;}
to {width:300px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {width:0px;}
to {width:300px;}
}
```

**JS**:

```
var count=1;
mf();
function mf()
{
document.getElementById("imge").src="img"+count+".jpg";

if(count<3)
count++;
else
count=1;
setTimeout("mf()",3000);
}
```

Comment: for image gallery infinite loop, u can use infinite,or else can specify the count no...

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called `animation-iteration-count` property of css. You can check it out [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-iteration-count.asp)

By setting the number you can fix the number of times the image has to show certain animation.
In your case you can set it to 3 as you have 3 images. You can also loop it infinitely using the count as `infinite`

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="imge" src="img1.jpg" height="200" width="300">
```

change to

```
<img class="imge" id="imge1" src="img1.jpg" height="200" width="300" style="display:none;"/>
<img class="imge" id="imge2" src="img2.jpg" height="200" width="300" style="display:none;"/>
<img class="imge" id="imge3" src="img3.jpg" height="200" width="300" style="display:none;"/>
```

so css
    #imge
should be 
    .imge

javascript

```
function mf()
{
  for(var i=1;i<4;i++)
  {
     document.getElementById("imge"+i).style.display="none";
  }  

  document.getElementById("imge"+count).style.display="block";

 if(count<3)
  count++;
 else
  count=1;
 setTimeout("mf()",3000);

}
```

when making the imge show,the animation will be triggered

Comment: not working this way...1st iamge displayed with transition but rest not

Answer (score 0):

Switch from `id`s to `class`es:

Instead of this:

```
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img id="imge" src="img1.jpg" height="200" width="300">
    </div>

    #slideshow{...}
    #imge{...}
```

to this:

```
    .slideshow{...}
    .imge{...}
```

The reason is that `id`s are *unique* (you can have only one), but classes not.

Hope this helps. Cheers